# Inserting div value into database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need to insert a div value into my database, as you can see down there in the code there is the  called Total Amount, this is giving me the final price i will have to pay, what i want is to insert the total amount value(which depends on what you are buying) into the database, for example if i pay 90$ i want the column Payment in my table to save the price i paid. I already done some php and im gonna insert it here.

```
`<div class="box step6">
        <h2 class="title">Step 5: Billing contact information</h2>
        <h3>Amount:</h3> <div class="pay one"></div></br>
        <h3>Early Bird Offer:</h3> <div class="pay two"></div></br>
        <h3>Total Amount:</h3> <div class="pay three"></div>
        <div class="pay-bt">
            <div class="paypal"><h3>Paypal</h3></div>
            <div class="card"><h3>Credit Card</h3></div>
            <div class="bank"><h3>Bank Transfer</h3></div>
        </div>`
```

Comment: add a hidden input

Comment: or get the html of div, and pass it via ajax :)

Comment: So from where you are getting this html. From a third party?

Comment: @ParantapParashar No i have a whole file with the HTML i just think it is not worth it to put the entire thing here because its giant.

Comment: @BenchmarksX Okay. Then you can use php DOM to find the inner html of the div.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the div content as html, you can use jquery `JSON.stringify($(".step6").html())` to get the content and encode html chars in php to prevent XSS

Answer (score -1):

Consider using ajax to send your data.

I would suggest using an ID for the div you want to target lets try `#pay-three`

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/your-php-script.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        total-amount: $('#pay-three').text(),
    }
}).done(function(data){
        alert('data sent');
});
```

In your script:

```
$total-amount=mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['total-amount']);
```

Comment: The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile You're right I think .text() would be more appropriate.

Comment: why are recommending the use of `mysql_*` functions?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile under the assumption of a MySQL database due to the tag in the question.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Why not instead educate me and show a solution that you think is better for this situation?

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I previously updated my answer to include the use of `mysqli_*` . Thanks for the correction.